# C# isn't correctly subtracting my values

Tags: c#

I have a set value and a user entry text box, where I have it set to only numeric entry's, followed by converting it to an int, which all works, but when I run the code and put in a number smaller than the set value it doesn't work out properly

TL:DR

(set value 20, user entered value 12, code returns -4)

```
private void LSum_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PassengersTXT.Text = LEFcPassanger.sendtext;
        DepartDateTXT.Text = LutonDepart.sendtext;
        DepTimeTXT.Text = LutonSat.sendtext;
        TravelTypeTXT.Text = LEClass.sendtext;
        DepartTXT.Text = Form2.sendtext;
        ArriveTXT.Text = LArrive.sendtext;

    }
if( TravelTypeTXT.Text == "First Class")
        {
            Seating.FirstClass -= Convert.ToInt32(PassengersTXT.Text);
            if (Seating.FirstClass <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Enough Seats in First Class", "ERROR!",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                LEFcPassanger form = new LEFcPassanger();
                form.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Seating.FirstClass -= Convert.ToInt32(PassengersTXT.Text);
                AppFin frm = new AppFin();
                frm.Show();
                this.Close();
            }


//seperate class
class Seating
{
    public static int FirstClass = 20;
    public static int BusinessClass = 36;
    public static int EconomyClass = 84;
    public static int TotalSeats = 140;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are subtracting 12 twice - once before the `if`, and once inside the `else` branch.

Rather than using `-=` right away, compare the value using `-`, like this:

```
var passengers = Convert.ToInt32(PassengersTXT.Text);
if (Seating.FirstClass-passengers < 0) { // Do not modify FirstClass yet
    ...
} else {
    // Now that we know that it's OK, apply modifications
    Seating.FirstClass -= passengers;
    ...
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: use the debugger

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I guess this depends on experience, but I think that this may be one of the occasions when using the debugger may slow you down.

Comment: Yes.  You also might want to use int.TryParse(PassengerTXT.Text, out intVariable),  and only convert the value once.

Comment: @DarrelLee Absolutely, this program can benefit a great deal from improved error handling.

Comment: thanks for the help but like i said "the code runs" so the debugger wasn't showing me why it wasn't working

Comment: I assume if you go to trouble of posting a question on SO.  You've already feeling stumped.   Why not use the internet as an automatic debugger?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight of course you wouldn't need the debugger to solve this when you're experienced, but teaching newcomers to use it when their code doesn't behave like they expect it to should be encouraged. They'll learn to debug *"by eye"* later with experience.

Comment: @Alfz the debugger lets you execute your code until it hits a breakpoint then you can run it step by step and inspect all intermediate values, so you know *exactly* what happens. Learn to use it, it's a mandatory skill in programming.

Comment: You can't debug code that doesn't run (except by eye).  I missed the error on my first read through..

Comment: ok a really nooby question, 
http://prntscr.com/btq4z0 first run through with all seats available
http://prntscr.com/btq5y3 5 passengers
http://prntscr.com/btq68o second run through
http://prntscr.com/btq6gm breakpoints is still empty (is this what you was talking about @LucasTrzesniewski)

Comment: @Alfz you're *not* using it properly - breakpoints won't just appear out of nowhere, *you* have to set them (with F9 on a given code expression). The debugger won't do anything besides just running your code unless you tell it to. I *can't* teach you how the debugger works in a comment, but I'm sure you'll find many tutorials on the matter.